# installing tor on redhat/centos server

Tags: centos, redhat, yum, tor

i want to install tor package on my centOS server

here is the output of `cat /proc/version` :

`Linux version 2.6.32-358.18.1.el6.x86_64 (mockbuild@c6b10.bsys.dev.centos.org) (gcc version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-3) (GCC) )`

when i run command `yum install tor` i get the following output :

```
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package tor.x86_64 0:0.2.4.17.rc-tor.1.rh19 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libssl.so.10(libssl.so.10)(64bit) for package: tor-0.2.4.17.rc-tor.1.rh19.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libcrypto.so.10(libcrypto.so.10)(64bit) for package: tor-0.2.4.17.rc-tor.1.rh19.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libcrypto.so.10(OPENSSL_1.0.1)(64bit) for package: tor-0.2.4.17.rc-tor.1.rh19.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libevent-2.0.so.5()(64bit) for package: tor-0.2.4.17.rc-tor.1.rh19.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: tor-0.2.4.17.rc-tor.1.rh19.x86_64 (tor)
       Requires: libcrypto.so.10(libcrypto.so.10)(64bit)
Error: Package: tor-0.2.4.17.rc-tor.1.rh19.x86_64 (tor)
       Requires: libevent-2.0.so.5()(64bit)
Error: Package: tor-0.2.4.17.rc-tor.1.rh19.x86_64 (tor)
       Requires: libcrypto.so.10(OPENSSL_1.0.1)(64bit)
Error: Package: tor-0.2.4.17.rc-tor.1.rh19.x86_64 (tor)
       Requires: libssl.so.10(libssl.so.10)(64bit)
You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

i've installed all of packages above using these commands:

```
yum install libcrypto.so.10
yum install libevent-2.0.so.5
yum install libssl.so.10
```

so , what's the problem?
thanks in advance

Comment: It might help for you to show you've researched the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, you didn't properly [follow the directions](https://www.torproject.org/docs/rpms.html.en).

You have a CentOS 6 system, but you are attempting to install Tor packages for Fedora 19.

The [directions](https://www.torproject.org/docs/rpms.html.en) state, in relevant part:

> **Fedora 18/19 and EL6 packages**
>   For Fedora 18, Fedora 19, RHEL 6 (and clones), use following repo file - substitute DISTRIBUTION with one of the following: fc/18, fc/19 or el/6 according to your distribution.

So, you were meant to remove the word `DISTRIBUTION` each time it appears in the repo file and replace them with `el/6`. Instead, you replaced them with `fc/19`.

Once you correct this, you will find that you are able to install the Tor package correctly.